# javascript prototype keyword in official documentation

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was reading the documentation on the `slice` function and saw that the title of the page was: "Array.prototype.slice()".

Why is the keyword `prototype` between `Array` and `slice()`?

Here is the page: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Any references to official documentation would be very helpful!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work?rq=1

Comment: The reason `.slice()` is available from every array instance is that it's a property of the Array prototype.

Comment: This answer contains a lot of details about constructor functions and the role of prototype: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 1):

This is the way JvaScript handles inheritance. It's a topic of depth, so this isn't a full answer, but essentially the `Array.prototype.slice` is saying "Slice is now a method available to objects of the class Array"

Read about prototypal inheritance to get a better idea: http://www.laktek.com/2011/02/02/understanding-prototypical-inheritance-in-javascript/

Comment: Thanks this really made a lot of since and why the word 'prototype' is specifically used!

Comment: The article you link to creates an instance of parent to set up prototype part of inheritance (bad) and then doesn't re use parent constructor by doing something like Parent.call(this) (very bad). The child now has parent instance specific members on it's prototype (hared)